# Liferay styling navbar dropdown links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, liferay

I'm making a Liferay theme and I'm having a real bad time trying to style the navigation menu. I've already changed classic theme hover functions on navigation links for those not being drop-down like this:

```
.aui #navigation .nav li.open>a{
    background-color: orange;
    color: #005373;
}
```

And that's in fact working fine. But i'm not being capable of styling those dropdown links... Tried this out:

1:

```
.aui #navigation .navbar-inner li:hover a.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: red;
}
```

2:

```
.aui #navigation .navbar-inner li.open> .dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: green;
}
```

3:

```
.aui #navigation .navbar-inner li:hover.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

4:

```
.aui #navigation .navbar-inner li:hover .dropdown-toggle active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: please show your html structure

Comment: Have you tried with Firebug (or equivalent developer tools for the browser of your least distrust) to determine the required selectors? I feel that it's a lot easier to try interactively than with a theme. Also, if you're basing your changes on the classic theme, it might contain more specific selectors than you expect - starting at Liferay's _styled theme it might be easier to find the required selectors.

Comment: yes, I tryed with firebug and chrome inspector. I was wondering it could be something like that, inheriting from classic could be the problem.

Comment: Is it changing from firebug or chrome inspector..??

Comment: No, that's the problem. I try to find the correct selector, but's seems to be imposible. Anyway what I was trying to do isn't so necesary. My objetive was colouring the <a> element while the mouse is over the <li> element. So instead of making it so complex I'll just let the <a> get the full container (<li>) and add the propper padding. It's not the same effect, but doesn't deserve so much time. thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as a partial solution, if you find yourself in the same situation (trying to colour `<a class="dropdown-toggle">` background in the `<li>` hover event, and you choosed to inherit from classic) the best advice I can give you is:

Just let the `<a class="dropdown-toggle">` element fill the `<li>` element, add enought padding.